# Pseudocode in java?

Tags: java, pseudocode

```
 String s = ""; 

    myf = new Finch();
    do
    {
        //Run the menu until quit or cancel is selected
        s = FinchMenu();
        //menu 1
        if (s.equals("Back and forward")) RunAccelerationTest(s);
    }
```

How would you convert something like this to pseudocode? For instance

```
String s = "";
```

Would the pseudocode for it be something like this?

```
Set s to ""
```

That just seems wrong to me.

Any help please? Thanks

Comment: pseudocode is what you make of it.

Comment: Read the *pseudocode* tag wiki: "Pseudocode is a compact and informal high-level description of a computer programming algorithm. It represents the code and may look similar to the code or code constructs, but it isn't actual code. It is a representation of the code or code construct."

Comment: There is no single, universally used pseudo-code language (other than Python, obviously! ;)) As long as what you write is unambiguous and resembles code, it *is* pseudo-code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pseudocode, i think, doesn't have a predefined syntax. just follow two rules:

- It should be plain english with common programming constructs.
- It should be generic, not specific to any language.

Following should fit:

```
Step 1: Initialize an empty string. (say str)

Step 2: Construct a new 'Finch' object.

Step 3: BEGIN LOOP

            Fetch 'FinchMenu' from 'Finch' object.

            assign 'FinchMenu' to 'str'

            IF 'FinchMenu' is "Back and forward"

                Call 'RunAccelerationTest' method with 'str' as argument.

            END IF

        END LOOP
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code is just a non language specific human readable walkthrough of whatever it is you are trying to do.

You could write `set s to ""` or even `make s an empty string` or anythign else that describes what it is this step is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking (this is totally how I use pseudo-code, rather than being anything set by a rule) I use pseudo-code to get rid of anything boilerplate or being syntactically correct.

For instance, say I have the following Java code...

```
import java.io.*;
class FileRead 
{
 public static void main(String args[])
  {
  try{
  // Open the file that is the first 
  // command line parameter
  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
  // Get the object of DataInputStream
  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
  String strLine;
  //Read File Line By Line
  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
  // Print the content on the console
  System.out.println (strLine);
  }
  //Close the input stream
  in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }
  }
}
```

My interpretation as pseudo-code would be something like...

```
main() {
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fileLocation);
BufferedReader br = BufferedReader(.....fstream);
String str;
while(br.readline!=empty, str=br.readline) {
  System.out(str);
}
}
```

Now this code is probably no use to anyone but me - but I know I can quickly look at it, see what it is and write it if necessary.  It's good for making quick notes in meetings etc, if I'm trying to write fast pseudo-code, things like exception handling aren't something I consider.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Comment: Ah - cool, I didn't realize this was in the same realm as StringBuilder vs StringBuffer.  Thank you for the link to your blog, I will have a gander :)

Comment: There are 20 postings a month of stackoverflow with this DataInputSTream+fstream code example so it is uprising common for something with is incorrect.  I would *love* to track down the original author of this code ;)